# Glove vector representation formula derivation - unsymmetric argument

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

On page 4 of paper "GloVe: Global Vectors for Word Representation".
The author said "Our final model should be invariant under this relabeling, but Eqn. (3) is not." My quesiton is why
$$
F\left(\left(w_i-w_j\right)^T \tilde{w}_k\right)=\frac{P_{i k}}{P_{j k}}
$$
is not symmetric?

Comment: It would be great if you could add link/refrence to the paper you are referring..

Comment: the paper's link is: https://nlp.stanford.edu/pubs/glove.pdf